# Properly configuring config.js in GitHub "Securing a web API with Azure AD"

Tags: node.js, adal

Refers to: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapi

I'm creating a simple POC app that needs to demonstrate using my company's Azure Active Directory for authenticating users. I followed all the steps in read.me, and got stuck at Step 6: Configure your server using config.js.

In that section, the author writes “You will need to update the sample to use your values for the metadata endpoint.” I know the values of my tenant and client IDs. I’m just not sure what I need to update in config.js.

I added clientID to the config object, but Node returns with an error that clientID cannot be null. I’m not sure where I should be putting this.

Here's the object that gets passed to app.js:

```
     // Don't commit this file to your public repos. This config is for first-run
 exports.creds = {
     mongoose_auth_local: 'mongodb://localhost/tasklist', // Your mongo auth uri goes here
     identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/093b18fb-a101-4e60-a38e-3a4af975a32e/.well-known/openid-configuration', // This is customized for your tenant.
     tenant : "retailsolutions.com",
     clientID : "093b18fb-a101-4e60-a38e-3a4af975a32e",
     // You may use the common endpoint for multi-tenant scenarios
     // if you do, make sure you set validateIssuer to false and specify an audience
     // as you won't get this from the Identity Metadata
     //
     //identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration',
     validateIssuer: true, // if you have validation on, you cannot have users from multiple tenants sign in
    passReqToCallback: false,
    loggingLevel: 'info' // valid are 'info', 'warn', 'error'. Error always goes to stderr in Unix.
 };
```

Would it be possible for someone who has had experience with this provide a good example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the client ID in the [options](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapi/blob/master/node-server/app.js#L38) being passed to Passport library as follows:

```
var options = {
...
clientID: config.creds.clientID,
...
}
```